# Responsive Image not Collapsing

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

My code generates this (code at the end of the post):

[image: Wide Browser Display]

When I drag in I want the images to resize, which they do (eventually I'm going to add some code that puts them below the main image after a certain size), but the second right hand image resizes in place, rather than staying below the image above it:

[image: Thinner browser windows]

Any idea how to solve it? Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
 body 
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img
{
    width: inherit;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper
{
    width: 710px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-column-left
{
    max-width: 66%;
    float: left;
}

#main-column-right
{
    max-width: 33%;
    float: right;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#news-feature
{
    width: 470px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

#news-item-four
{
    width: 230px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    max-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#news-item-five
{
    width: 230px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    max-height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="main-column-left">
                <div id="news-feature">
                    <img src="Images/NewsFeatureImage.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="main-column-right">
                <div id="news-item-four">
                    <img src="Images/NewsImageFour.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div id="news-item-five">
                    <img src="Images/NewsImageFive.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because you have a fixed height to the parent `.news-item-four` : `height: 160px;`

Comment: Sometimes, you just need someone else to look at the code! Well spotted, I can't accept you comment as an answer as it is a comment, if you want to add it as an answer and I'll accept - cheers.

Comment: http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/EFfey

Comment: Valid the answer of @3rror404. I'm not looking after reputation especially

Comment: Ok mate - well you fixed it and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the fixed height on `.news-item-four`

```
#news-item-four
{
    width: 230px;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*height: 160px;*/
    max-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

At the moment, the images are resizing but the container(`.news-item-four`) is not.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wzYxv/)